# В чём разница между объявлением счётчика внутри и вне цикла for?

Tags: c#, c++, c, циклы, for

В чем заключается разница при разном определении итерационной переменной? Влияет ли на выделяемую память?

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < someVal; i++) { }
```

и

```
for (int i = 0; i < someVal; i++) { }
```

Comment: В с++ участок памяти может быть использован другими локальными переменными, которые обьявлены в других {} если такие есть (2-4 байта, версия и производитель с/с++ влияет ). В c# разницы не будет.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Это будет влиять только на область видимости переменной `i`. В первом случае вы можете обратиться к переменной вне цикла, например:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < someVal; i++) { };
i = 2 + 2;
```

Во втором случае область видимости `i` ограничена телом цикла.

Comment: Более полезен, наверное, вариант с break, чтобы выяснить, на какой итерации оборвался цикл

Comment: а как же вопрос 2?

Comment: @nick_n_a: А на память не влияет, скорее всего счётчик будет вообще вытеснен в регистр.

Comment: А если локальных переменных штук 10?

Comment: @nick_n_a, а если программист - идиот?

Comment: @nick_n_a: ... то компилятор скорее всего всё равно вытеснит счётчик самого внутреннего цикла в регистр.

Comment: если есть сомнения по поводу компилятора - открываем http://gcc.godbolt.org/ и медитируем на собранный код.

Comment: @KoVadim: С конкретно данным кодом, пустой цикл оптимизатор скорее всего просто выкинет полностью.

Comment: естественно. Компиляторы сейчас достаточно умные. Мое любимое - "не пытайся обмануть компилятор":)

Answer (score 12):

В дополнение к совершенно правильному ответу @Flownee: то, как и где именно объявлены переменные, не важно. Важно лишь то, в каком месте в коде эта переменная всё ещё нужна.

Современные компиляторы на популярных платформах проводят агрессивную оптимизацию, и используют память переменной для других переменных не в конце области её видимости, а реально *как только* она больше не нужна в коде. В отсутствие использования переменной после цикла оба варианта равносильны, и по идее дадут одинаковое распределение памяти.